# Stepped Area Google charts wrong visualization

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google charts Stepped Area in my project, I have 2 data columns (datetime,state).

The problem is when the change in time is dynamic and not fixed the chart gets abnormal like this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lrpn1zv/31/), however when the data points are in fixed time change, the chart is drawn correctly for example in this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lrpn1zv/30/) the points are one every 100 milliseconds.

Example 1 data

```
      ['Date',  'State'],
      [new Date(1534078983500), 3],
      [new Date(1534078983880), 1],
      [new Date(1534080441460), 3],
      [new Date(1534080441840), 1],
      [new Date(1534080533960), 3],
      [new Date(1534080534330), 1]
```

Example 2 data

```
      ['Date',  'State'],
      [new Date(1534078983100), 3],
      [new Date(1534078983200), 1],
      [new Date(1534078983300), 3],
      [new Date(1534078983400), 1],
      [new Date(1534078983500), 3],
      [new Date(1534078983600), 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart#data-format) for the `SteppedAreaChart`,

the Data Type for the x-axis should be --> `'string'`

although it may work with dates, the results may be inconsistent

instead, use the [DateFormat class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat) to convert the date to a timestamp string

see following working snippet...

here, a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class) is used to create a calculated column for the timestamp...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date',  'State'],
    [new Date(1534078983500), 3],
    [new Date(1534078983880), 1],
    [new Date(1534080441460), 3],
    [new Date(1534080441840), 1],
    [new Date(1534080533960), 3],
    [new Date(1534080534330), 1]
  ]);

  var formatTime = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'HH:ss.SSSS a'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return formatTime.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0));
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: 'string'
  }, 1]);

  var options = {
    title: 'The decline of \'The 39 Steps\'',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Accumulated Rating',
      ticks: [{ v: 0, f: '' }, { v: 1, f: 'Close' }, { v: 2, f: 'CLG/OPG' }, { v: 3, f: 'Open' }, { v: 4, f: '' }]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

if you need to use the `explorer` option,
you can use a number instead of a string

use the formatted value to display the actual dates,
and build custom ticks for the x-axis using the same approach...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date',  'State'],
    [new Date(1534078983500), 3],
    [new Date(1534078983880), 1],
    [new Date(1534080441460), 3],
    [new Date(1534080441840), 1],
    [new Date(1534080533960), 3],
    [new Date(1534080534330), 1]
  ]);

  var formatTime = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'HH:ss.SSSS a'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return {
        v: row,
        f: formatTime.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0))
      };
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: 'number'
  }, 1]);

  var xTicks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < view.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    addTick(i);
  }
  function addTick(i) {
    xTicks.push({
      v: view.getValue(i, 0),
      f: view.getFormattedValue(i, 0)
    });
  }

  var options = {
    explorer: {},
    hAxis: {
      ticks: xTicks
    },
    title: 'The decline of \'The 39 Steps\'',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Accumulated Rating',
      ticks: [{ v: 0, f: '' }, { v: 1, f: 'Close' }, { v: 2, f: 'CLG/OPG' }, { v: 3, f: 'Open' }, { v: 4, f: '' }]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried this solution before but the issue is the graph now is considered as a normal chart not a time series chart so I can't add zoom-in feature to it.However with fixed time change it supports zooming like this example https://jsfiddle.net/3Lrpn1zv/90/